# The chromedriver file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH

Tags: c#, selenium, macos, selenium-webdriver, nunit

Формат драйвера, ниже прописал ошыбку
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();                            options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins", 1);                            options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.content_settings.plugin_whitelist.adobe-flash-player", 1);                            options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.content_settings.exceptions.plugins.*,*.per_resource.adobe-flash-player", 1);                           options.AddUserProfilePreference("PluginsAllowedForUrls", "http:/ ");                            options.AddUserProfilePreference("PluginsAllowedForUrls", TestDataResource.MainPageURL);
Browser = new ChromeDriver(options);

Выскакиевает даная ошыбка, драйвер лежит в корне, подскажите если есть идеи:
OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException : The chromedriver file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: [options.BinaryLocation = "\path\to\chrome";](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeOptions.htm)

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: На здоровье. Оставил ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите расположение вашего драйвера в [настройках](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeOptions.htm)

```
options.BinaryLocation = "\path\to\chrome";
```